# How does `gradle install` generate the `pom.xml` files

Tags: java, maven, gradle, pom.xml

When I run `gradle install` it generates nice `pom.xml` files in every subproject.

Where can I see the source code that accomplishes that?

As per [Maven plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html), there's something about the [Upload](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.html) task, but its documentation and the source code yield nothing concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `gradle-maven-VERSION.jar` to your dependencies and debug the plugin yourself. The corresponding source code sits in your gradle installation, or on github: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/maven/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal

To give you a head start: bulk of the code sits in `DefaultMavenPom` class.
It is created in `DefaultMavenPomFactory.create()` with some dummy values:

- `MavenProject.EMPTY_PROJECT_GROUP_ID`
- `MavenProject.EMPTY_PROJECT_ARTIFACT_ID`
- `MavenProject.EMPTY_PROJECT_VERSION`

Then, `AbstractMavenResolver.publish(IvyModulePublishMetadata moduleVersion)` is called,
which, among others:

- Fills in basic pom data based on actual artifact in `DefaultArtifactPom.assignArtifactValuesToPom()`
- Fills in dependencies - they are filled in with `DefaultMavenPom.getGeneratedDependencies()`
- Writes generated file